# Is there a way to declare a specified set of values in method parameter in Scala?

Tags: java, scala, methods

Let say I have a method to get `student_subject` table queries based on `status`, and this `status` can be `'failed'`, `'passed'`, `'ongoing'`.

How do I do it in a method rather than 3 different methods?
Is it possible that I declare what type of accepting `String` in the method parameters?

Comment: You could use a [Case Class](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/case-classes.html), or a Java [Enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean?  Right now it sounds like you're looking for a way to query based on the status from a single method (e. g. `StudyDAO.byStatus(status: String)`)

Comment: Yes, something like that, but i want the status to accept only certain set of accepted values..
@SeanVieira

Comment: As Elliott points out, why not an enum?  If you want a subclass of strings (e. g. `type Status = 'failed' | 'passed' | 'ongoing'`) then the concept you are most likely looking for is singleton types (but an enum should do just fine).

Answer (score 1):

Just use traits and singletons

```
sealed trait Status //sealed doesn't allow to extend this trait in another compilation unit
case object Failed extends Status
case object Passed extends Status
case object Ongoing extends Status

def getStidentSubject(status: Status) = status match {
   case Failed => ...
   case Passed => ...
   case Ongoing => ...
}
```

Alternatively you could just match strings but it's much less type-safe.

If you need more enum-like capabilities in Scala (preserving ADT's advantages) I'd recommend Enumeratum library.